# Mysql insert foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, key

I'm confused as to how to insert the values for a foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE Cities (
    name        VARCHAR(20),
    state_name  VARCHAR(20),

    PRIMARY KEY (name, state_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (state_name) REFERENCES States(name),
);
```

How do I go about inserting values into the table, Cities?(I already inserted values into table State)

Comment: You insert - have you had some problem with inserting to cities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be designing your tables to use `id`s.  The tables should look more like this:

```
create table states (
    state_id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    unique (name)
);

create table cities (
    city_id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    state_id int,
    unique (name, state_id),
    foreign key (state_id) references states(state_id),
);
```

Then you can populate the tables like this:

```
insert into states (name)
    values ('New Mexico');

insert into cities (name)
    select 'Truth or Consequences', s.state_id
    from states s
    where s.name = 'New Mexico';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert values into the `name` and `state_name` columns as usual. But the `state_name` value needs to be in the `States` table `name` column. For example:

```
INSERT INTO Cities (name, state_name)
VALUES ('Springfield', 'Illinois');
```